# srand(time(NULL)) in C++

Tags: c++

If I comment out the line with `srand`, the program will work, but there is no seed so the values will be the same each time. The assignment requires that I use `rand`, `srand`, and `time` to have the dice function be completely random.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int rollDice();
// function declaration that simulates the rolling of dice

int main() {

    int roll1 = rollDice();

    int roll2 = rollDice();

    // define, initialize, and combine dice roll total

    int total;

    total = 0;

    total = roll1 + roll2;

    * this is where a bunch of stuff is output to the screen from the dice rolls, using total as well as some other stuff that is being calculated, i left it out for simplicity*

}

// function to simulate a random dice roll

int rollDice() {

    int r;

    srand (time(NULL));

    r = (rand() % 6) + 1;

    return r;

}
```

Comment: `srand` has to be called only once in your program.

Comment: [Watch this.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: #include <std DON'T PUT SRAND INSIDE THE LOOP!> answer. Seems like about two of these each week.

Answer (score 6):

Put `srand` in the main and call it once.
You have to use the seed once to get all the results from a random sequence.

Here you restart the sequence every time you roll the dice.

See the documentation for [`srand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand)

Comment: THANKS! none of the answers I saw on google mentioned that the srand had to be initialized in the main program!

Comment: @user2766542: The main thing to understand is how pseudo-random number generation works. You seed the random number generator, and that gives you a reproducible sequence of numbers. So you seed it once, normally in `main()` but not necessarily. If you seed it every time, you will get poor results. `time()` has a granularity of one second. So if you ask for multiple random numbers within a second they may all have the same value!